# phonegap android camera: crash when "correctOrientation" option set

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I know people have asked similar questions but I am having a serious issue.

anyone who uses phone gap knows it is definitely not the end all to solutions for an app!

but any way here is my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, 
correctOrientation: true });
```

the problem is when I add the correctOrientation, my freaking app has some sort of memory leak because it closes out and has an error. When i take out the correct orientation parameter, its fine, except for the fact that the orientation is wrong! does anyone have a work around to get my pictures' orientations correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
```

-->

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="mysecond" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Comment: [I think you may be out of luck on this.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1826?attachmentOrder=desc)

Comment: @Dnaso may I see your manifest file?

Comment: @Dnaso which cordova js version you are using?

Comment: the manifest does have the camera permission I will append to my question and I am using 2.3.0. I figured since its out of beta it should be stable, I guess not :(

Comment: I didnt take out any of the permissions I am doing a kitchen sink project for someone, everything else is pretty good (sort of) but the camera and video are such a pain.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for being so optimistic!

Comment: Well that bug report indicates that they don't think it can be fixed. It may be something that varies from device to device I guess.

Comment: oh wow really? so how the hell do phone gap developers make use of the camera? doesnt it render it kind of useless at that point?

Comment: I guess it's something people do on a server - just grab the picture and upload it or something.

Comment: Can you run "adb logcat" so we can see the stack trace?

Comment: I figured out the answer , if you set target width it makes the img size considerably less and  doesn't crash , thank you

Answer (score 6):

Thanks guys, I figured it out. You have to set the "target size" if you dont the img size is HUGE and will cause a memory overflow. I set the target width to 720 and the quality to 50, and all was well,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Phonegap's Hydration - I'm not 100% certain, but that seemed to make my camera app crash a few times. Removing that seemed to help. I've also tried adding `targetWidth: 400` and turned Hydration back on, which seemed to work as well.

Comment: I didn't even know phonegap offered that (although cool) is it enabled by default ?

Comment: No, hydration isn't enabled by default, but it can significantly cut down on development time. I think the main issue has to do with setting the image quality and size to prevent memory overflow as is suggested in Dnaso's post

Comment: it was the issue. if you dont set the image size and quality the images are like 4 MB